# Show Three records of MySql table in three columns of html table Using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I Need to show three records of MySql table in three different column using php.My Query is

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE Id IN(1,2,3)
```

I want to show the result as here
[image]

How can i Write LOOP for it?like

```
while(loop condition)
{
//what will go here?

}
```

**UPDATE:** First row fields will show in first column of html table and second record fields will display in second column and so on...I am not asking only show three records

Comment: in php with e.g. while()

Comment: you want show only first three records or id 1,2,3 records

Comment: What you mean, `what goes here`? Check 3 columns css/html on the net.

Comment: No I want to show all fields of these ids...ids might be 4,5,6...but not more than three

Comment: SELECT * FROM `table1` limit 1,3 try this

Comment: @lolka_bolka:Its not that simple,First record will display in first column and second will display in second coloumn

Comment: If I understood the question , try to use limit 3 then you also use order by id then descending or ascending .in your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP saying, it's not so simple. But it is.

So, you have 2 ways to do it.

First. In this case, you are loop through on the 3 columns. Fetch the first row. This put all the data into a div. Class name is `column_1`. Do it for the other 3. Then floating the divs to left to each other.

```
$i = 1;
while($row = $db->fetch_row()) {
    ?>
<div class="column_<?php echo $i; ?>">
    <div class="picture">
        <?php echo $row["image"]; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
        <?php echo $row["desc"]; ?>
    </div>
    ... and so on...

</div>
<?php
    $i++;
}
```

Second one, when you first collect the data about 3 rows, and then put them into a table rows by row.

```
<?php
    while($row = $db->fetch_row()) {
        $results[] = $row;
    }
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $result[0]['image'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $result[1]['image'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $result[2]['image'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $result[0]['desc'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $result[1]['desc'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $result[2]['desc'] ?></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

**EDIT**

I forgot that, there is a third solution. You can just build the table empty, and then you can update the cells with an ajax call with jQuery.

Comment: See my third option too :)

Answer (score 0):

One way of looping through them is `foreach()`

assuming you have your results in `$results` array:

```
foreach($results as $result) {
   //create your table
   $result['id']; //has the item id
   $result['title']; //has item title
   //and so on...
}
```

[HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp) is a great tutorial on looping through mysql result sets :D (W3Schools)

Another one [HERE](http://jadendreamer.wordpress.com/2011/02/09/php-tutorial-looping-through-displaying-a-result-set/)

To provide a answer to your comment you must understand how HTML tables work...
`<tr>` = table row 
`<td>` = table data

You are asking for an entire source code, and this is NOT that place, we don't do your job for you, but if you want, you will have to pay me :) and I am not sure that you agree with this :)

[HERE](http://www.htmltutorials.ca/lesson12.htm) is a good and easy to understand tutorial on HTML tables.

Comment: My Question is,How i will show first row of db in first column of html?

Comment: I am not asking for complete code....You are asking for money directly here that means you are misusing this portal..#ShameONU

Comment: there you go! :D updated my answer ;) hope this suits your needs!

Comment: :)) I am on SO for more then a year, I am not asking you for money I am simply telling you that if you want me to do this, you will have to pay for my work. If you want my help on something that you already started and you have something that you don't understand (like how to loop through records) I will be more then glad to help you. But don't ask for my personal time to give you ready-to-go code when you come here with a print screen from probably a website that you like and wanna copy ;)

Comment: btw, if that IS a print screen from another website, I suggest you simply inspect the table with inspect element (F12 in chrome or right click -> inspect element) and check out how that table is coded ... but that is just to much work for your lazy ass aint it?

Comment: My Question is not how to loop through records...if you look into my display screen how i want so it could not be done by that loop.loop displays for example, Name,Email,Phone of first employee and then comes to second employee..but i want to display Name of first then name of second and so on

Comment: NO! you CLEARLY don't understand the concept! loops breaks down your array is separate elements! you can rearrange the elements then like pieces in a puzzle. This can be done with while, for, foreach and so on. You lack basic understanding of how a table in HTML is done!! This is your issue. Read some tutorials on tables, how to arrange data in them, or just drop what you are doing. This is eating too much of your time, and ours ;)

Comment: I got the answer from @lolka.People like you is only for down voting as that is what you can do.nothing else!!

Comment: =)) you know you can check my activity by clicking my username and see my questions and my answers... you may or may not be right, but because of people like you the humanity is so retarded! you know how to copy and paste and do nothing else. At least I work for what I know and I try to give back... But I HATE lazy ma'fu*kers like yourself ;) I wish you a sad Christmas and a crappy new year ;)!

Comment: you do know that I can down vote you only once, right? And for your information, I haven't down voted you AT ALL! Those 4 down votes that you have come from other users who think that you are as stupid as I say ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
while ($data=mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

}
```

Comment: Its not that much simple as you think

Comment: what you want please describe here

Comment: do not use mysql_* function, they are deprecated. use mysqli or PDO instead. Also, he just want to know the logic of this, not what should go into the while.